# Bootstrap 5 navbar-nav to fill whole screen when collapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

Hey friends whats up............!

I am building this website using bootstrap 5 and I do have a navbar toggler on it........!
Its working fine but I do want it do fill the full width of screen when toggled.........!

Tried some stuff but could not do it. Here is my code. I appreciate any help................!

[image]

```css
/***** Top menu *****/

.navbar {
  background: #000;
  transition: all .6s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 88px;
}

.navbar.navbar-no-bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
}


.navbar-brand {
  width: 136px;
  background: url(/assets/imgs/logo_jpad.png) left center no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 60px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.navbar-nav {

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  padding-top: 24px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-no-bg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bootstrap 5 One Page Website Tutorial</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler"
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#top-content">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#services">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#about-us">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#portfolio">FAQ</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb1 btn-jpad">Request a quote</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the container class OR move it up (in example) so it encapsulates all of your nav. Not sure where this came from, but it appears to be a design choice to have the  collapse smaller. But this will fix it.

```css
/***** Top menu *****/

.navbar {
  background: #000;
  transition: all .6s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 88px;

}

.navbar.navbar-no-bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
}


.navbar-brand {
  width: 136px;
  background: url(/assets/imgs/logo_jpad.png) left center no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 60px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.navbar-nav {

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  padding-top: 24px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-no-bg navbar-dark">

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bootstrap 5 One Page Website Tutorial</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler"
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#top-content">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#services">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#about-us">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link" href="#portfolio">FAQ</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb1 btn-jpad">Request a quote</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
 
      </nav>
          </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Danielle, thank you. I am learning so took some tutorial on the internet and did it.

Thank you again for helping.

Comment: I wish you all the luck in the learning process, and always happy to help. :)

Comment: Thank you! I am really enjoying learning it. Danielle, it is working on that matter, but on the other hand now it is not aligned as I expected on desktop.

I want to align more to the right. If you run the code snippet and click full page will you see how it was before you answer.

I tried some padding here and margin there but could not get it to work, can you help me?